# find a in log equation with root in graph

Tags: polynomials

[image: ${y = log(x + a)}$]

> ${y = log(x + a)}$
>
> find a

I have not encountered log equations before. I can plug 3 into the equation from the root but I'm not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key fact
is that
$\log(1) = 0$
in any base.

Since your curve
is zero at $x=-3$,
then,
if $\log(x+a) = 0$,
you must have
$x+a = -3+a = 1$
so
$a = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

my answer :

from the graph, at $x=-3$, y=0 so i get

$\log(-3+a)=0$

$-3+a=e^{0}=1$

$a=4$